# Linux partitions for a web server?

Tags: linux, partitioning, lamp

I am building a production and a development server for a web portal. It is based on a LAMP application that also uses local storage for files.

I organized the files as follow:

```
/srv/myapp/www     HTDocs
/srv/myapp/config  Portal configuration
/var/lib/myapp     Files used by the portal
```

For the disk partitions I propose this:

```
/dev/sda2        25G  /
/dev/sda3         5G  /srv
/dev/sda4         5G  /var
/dev/sda5        10G  /var/lib
```

Is it a good idea to mount a partition on `/var/lib`?

I guess this is a good idea because `/var/lib` already contains the database for my LAMP project.

Asked differently: why is it a bad idea to do it so?

Comment: `/var/lib` is used by some rather important stuff in your system, if you lose it you can be left with a severely damaged server. It would be safer to create a file system for your stuff, but mount it as `/var/lib/app`. Static content is usually on `/var/www`, so your hybrid solution (some in `/var`, some in `/srv/`) doesn't make much sense to me. A single FS with `/srv/www` and `/srv/app` (and the config in `/etc`) would cleaner and easier to manage IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind, what size, and what amount of files will the portal be using. I'd actually propose to just mount 15G on `/var/`, since the web server will write a lot in `/var/log` as well and I doubt you'd need 10G for the portal's files. Usually if you know that the same mountpoint will have heavy IO, it is nice to have it as a seperate partition, however, as it is an LAMP-based app, the web server will write **a lot** into `/var/log`. And besides that, `/var` in general is one of the most dynamic mountpoints in Linux, since they are variable files and often get written/read. Thus my suggestion is to mount more space to `/var/`, there isn't a big need for a seperate `/var/lib` partition.

Also, if the web portal will generate a lot of activity, you should clear your older logs when you don't need them anymore to save up space (you can check [logrotate](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/logrotate/logrotate.8.en.html)).

Comment: If you are asking this question you should most likely just be using a single partition for everything. Investigate LVM if you want to carve up a drive into partitions.